# How to select specific fields including withCount

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to return specific columns including the reviews_count one.

Here is the non-optimized query (working):

```
Model::withCount('reviews')->get();
```

Here is what I try to achieve (doesn't work):

```
Model::withCount('reviews')->select('id','name','reviews_count')->get();
```

What should I do to include the reviews_count in the select query using eloquent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `withCount` method will add an additional custom select, so there is no need to include it in your select method. Simply place the `select` method before `withCount`, like the example below:

```
Model::select('id','name')->withCount('reviews')->get();
```

above will generate below query:

```
select "id", "name", (select count(*) from "reviews" where "invoices"."id" = "reviews"."invoice_id") as "reviews_count" from "invoices"
```

If you place the `select` method after other selects, such as `withCount`, it will override or replace them. Another approach is to use the `addSelect` method, but you will still need to remove the default select, as shown below:

```
Model::select([])->withCount('reviews')->addSelect('id','name')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I needed to get the `posts_count` of each user and I used the following code to do so:

```
use App\Models\User;

User::select(['name', 'id'])
    ->withCount('posts')
    ->get();
```

As illustrated in the previous code I selected the **exact columns that I needed** and then **the relationship items count** and not the versa.

I hope it helps you :)