# How to add a count of the data on a has many relation laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables Location and customers the relationship is has many. One location can have many customers

So what i want is to get the one location and how many customers are registered to that location

on my LocationController i have this code

```
  return $this->location::withCount(["customer"])->select('location_id')->whereLocationId($data->location_id)->first();
```

and on the Location Model

```
    public function customer()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
}
```

the return of this is just the location_id and no customer count

Comment: btw, "If you're combining `withCount` with a `select` statement, ensure that you call `withCount` after the `select` method:" [Laravel 9.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Counting Related Models - Relationship Counting & Custom Select Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-counting-and-custom-select-statements)

Comment: omy god thank you it working now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select specific fields including withCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648172/how-to-select-specific-fields-including-withcount)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `withCount()` eloquent method

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models